# Работа с операторами Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

***Всем привет!***

У меня есть на БД Array `workers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Я должен c помощью Sequelize должен проверить есть ли UserId в Array, точнее беру req.user.id от JWT_decode

Пробовал таких:

```
const smthing = await SMTHING.findAll({where: {
  workers: {
    [Op.contains]: req.user.id
  }
}})
res.status(200).json({smthing,
  workers: [req.user.id]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил:

```
const smthing = await SMTHING.findAll({where: {
  workers: {
    [Op.contains]: [req.user.id] /* Добавил квадратных скобок */
  }
}})
res.status(200).json({smthing,
  workers: [req.user.id]
})
```